# firestore.onSnapshot callback function is blocking render process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore's onSnapshot() method to listen to a collection of ~5,000 documents. In the callback passed to onSnapshot, I am taking the snap and formatting the docs into an array and object.

```
db.onSnapshot(snap => {
      const list = [];
        const ref = {};
        for (let i = 0, size = snap.size; i < size; i++) {
          const doc = snap.docs[i];
          const id = doc.id;
          const data = doc.data();
          list.push(data);
          ref[id] = { ...data };
        }
    // Save list and ref to redux store.
  }
```

This process has been working well with smaller collections. However, now with this larger collection, when a user submits a new document to the collection, the "success" prompt that a user sees is blocked by the for loop.

To elaborate: When a user submits a new document, `db.add(newDocument)` is called. In the `.then()` we are re-rendering the page to show the user a confirmation message. At the same time though, the snapshot listener has detected a change in the collection and is now looping over all 5,000 documents again. This only takes a second or two but it produces a noticeable "lag" for the user.

How should this process be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably:

- Preserve the value of `ref` for as long as the listener stays attached - don't recreate it each time.
- Iterate [snap.docChanges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#doc-changes) so you will only have to process those changes that will result in your prior `ref` contents to change.  This will be indicated in the [type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange.html#type) of the change.

This should drastically reduce the number of objects being created and destroyed every time something changes.